# How to configure jailed apache to be accessible on the network

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd, jail

I have jailed `apache` on freebsd on a private network with ip address `192.168.100.174`, I have another apache server running on the host but it is configured to listen on its other IP addresses but this.

Now what more do I need do to make the jailed apache accessible on another machine on the same network? I have an `index.html` page in the DocumentRoot `/usr/local/www/apache22/data`. I want to be able to access it through the URL `http://192.168.100.174/`

`apache` is working OK in the jail:

```
[root@mambo-webhost /]# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache22 status
apache22 is running as pid 87597.
[root@mambo-webhost /]#
```

Thanks

### =====

I have two versions of of apache running : one on the host and one in a jail. I installed jailed apache right with in the jail and I'm trying to run the newer PHP version in the Jail. I don't know if I'm really doing the right thing here but I have not come across any documentation on how to achieve this.

I can telnet into 192.168.100.174 on port 80

```
sandbox2:~$ telnet 192.168.100.174 80
Trying 192.168.100.174...
Connected to 192.168.100.174.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

...only if apache running on the host (jail host) is listening on the IP address 192.168.100.144. But I need the jailed apache to be the server accessed for request to `http://192.168.100.174/`. Is this possible?

`netstart -rn` output

```
# netstat -rn
Routing tables
...
192.168.100.145    d0:27:88:03:19:92  UHLW        1     1605    rl0   1068
192.168.100.173    00:c1:28:00:48:db  UHLW        1      507    lo0
192.168.100.174    00:c1:28:00:48:db  UHLW        1        1    lo0
...
```

`192.168.100.145` is the other machine requesting for `http://192.168.100.174/`

`ipfw list` output

```
# ipfw list
ipfw: getsockopt(IP_FW_GET): Protocol not available
```

Comment: If you jail has the IP `192.168.100.174` that's where the (jailed) Apache should be listening -- From what you describe above it sounds like your host Apache may have `Listen *` in its configuration somewhere (and is grabbing on to the IP the jailed Apache wants to use) -- try shutting down the Apache daemon on the host system to troubleshoot (or ensure that it's not listening on the jailed Apache's IP)

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the index page locally (from the command prompt)

```
telnet 192.168.100.174  80

...

GET /
```

Check your firewall rules, (possibly: **ipfw list**) to ensure inbound traffic is permitted on port 80, on that interface. Also check your [routing table](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-routing.html) to ensure the other machine is on the local network segment.

```
netstat -rn
```